# Is there a way to find out WHO sent me a life threatening text?

Tags: wifi, spoofing, sms

Recently I received several text messages from TWO different numbers that I did not recognize. I called the numbers back, and texted them, but there was no answer, or vm. I googled them as well, and no hits. Thus, I contacted my local authorities who stated the calls definitely came from someone who utilized a "text app. The investigator stated it is impossible to find out exactly WHO texted it, or what number it REALLY originated from, and that it is unlikely I would be able to prosecute UNLESS I knew the REAL number/account/phone that was used.

He said, these text app companies purposely dont keep records, and know that people are disguising their number. Odds are they used a wifi connection, Is this accurate? Or does anyone know how I could pinpoint who sent those texts? Thanks!

Comment: yes, the police is correct

Comment: there are multiples of this question here, so I'll close as-is

Comment: You didn't indicate exactly what type of text message but if it was a generic SMS text, then it had to be cellular **not WiFi**. It's possible the originator used a WiFi link into a cellular service, but there's always a trail, often financial if not technical. The unfortunate reality is that most Law Enforcement simply is not competent to pursue something like this and won't bring in the required expertise short of very powerful drivers.